# Get path from Environment variables in windows

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I already set environment variable using batch file in windows. i am struct in load in that environment variable into one text file. i searched in stack overflow, but not getting my solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: question is how to load environment variable in my property file. 
Ex: i configured like this ${demo_home}/log in that property file. but not setting this demo_home but i am having in environment variable.

Comment: So you want the program that reads the property file to look up the environment variable?  Is it your program that reads the property file?  How do you go about reading the file?  What language are you using?  What part of the problem are you stuck on?  Post some code.

Comment: In java language, i need to load in log4j.property 
ex:log4j.appender.Daily.File=${demo_home}/Rflite.log

Comment: Please edit your question to include the necessary details.  That doesn't look like Java code to me, please include the actual code that reads the file.

Comment: In java application log4j.property i am having this line, log4j.appender.Daily.File=${Retail_HOME}/Rflite.log .
also i already set Retail_HOME path as environment variable. my question is how to load that path in my property

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2263929/886887

Comment: in java application application.proeprty is different and logger property also different. i dint process in logger property like map<string> conversion. so it is not duplicate

Comment: The answers in the proposed duplicate explain how you can change your code so that it does what you want it to do.  Why doesn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the contents of you PATH variable to a text file using windows cmd, use the following command:

```
D:\>path>myPath.txt
```

The myPath.txt file will be created in your D drive in this case.

Comment: okey. but i want to load without using cmd.
 like above i mentioned wise i want to load