# react-native-config unable to use env variables in build.gradle

Tags: react-native, build.gradle, react-native-config

I have `react-native-config` set up and use it in javascript no problem but am unable to use it like this in `build.gradle`.

```
release {
     if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
         storeFile file(project.env.get("MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE"))
         storePassword project.env.get("MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD")
         keyAlias project.env.get("MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS")
         keyPassword project.env.get("MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD")
     }
}
```

versions

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.5
react: 16.0.0
react-native-config: 0.11.1
```

Output

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease`
... shortened output
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In gradle build you use `project.env.get("VAR NAME")`

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'env' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project. Any idea what am missing ?

Comment: Most of the time it means my build.gradle is wrong. Add/change this "apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"" at the top (below: import com.android.build.OutputFile)

Comment: Thanks it worked. How to access the env config in gradle.properties file ?

Comment: You can't. You would need to post-process the properties somehow as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263944/2382650). Currently, Gradle does not offer any such functionality to "custom load" gradle.properties

Answer (score 1):

Although autolinking setup all for you, still need to set up this manually to use it in `build.gradle`

> apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() +
> "/dotenv.gradle"

to the very top, right below `import com.android.build.OutputFile` in `android/app/build.gradle` file

https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#extra-step-for-android

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the file in `MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE` doesn't exist. What value do you have in there? Does the file exist in the same folder?

But also notice you shouldn't store signing secrets in `.env`; From the react-native-config readme:

> Keep in mind this module doesn't obfuscate or encrypt secrets for packaging, so do not store sensitive keys in .env. It's [basically impossible to prevent users from reverse engineering mobile app secrets](https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/), so design your app (and APIs) with that in mind.

What you can do instead is use a Gradle property file to keep your secrets. For instance, in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=myapp
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=abc
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=def
```

These are then just available in `build.gradle`:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile "myapp.keystore"
        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
```