# Access Intellij Environment variables in Java application properties (not Spring)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij on my Windows laptop and I want to use environment variables in application.properties. Below is an example of application.properties.

```
server=%APP_SERVER%
```

I have added a new user environment variable as shown below through IntelliJ Run/Deebug Configurations.

```
APP_SERVER=localhost
```

But I see that when I run the application, it is failing to replace this environment property. I tried using ${APP_SERVER} instead of %APP_SERVER% but still no use. Any idea why this is not working.

Comment: How are you reading your application.properties file?

Comment: There is an answer to similar problem. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263944/4635750

Comment: @NodirNasirov, I don't prefer getEnv solution as the other post describes. Thanks anyway

Comment: @yole, I am using Apache Commons PropertiesConfiguration

Configuration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration("application.properties");

I know that I can use getEnv approach but I don't prefer this approach. I would like to use CI/CD pipeline to replace these variables in application.properties later while deploying onto server. And also, if I am running locally (or debugging) from IntelliJ, I like them to get replaced by environment variables

Comment: `I am using Apache Commons PropertiesConfiguration` - have you consulted the library documentation about how to properly reference environment variables: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html it seems one must use `env` prefix for this: `java.home = ${env:JAVA_HOME}`.

Comment: Yes, ${env:JAVA_HOME} also doesn't work