# Does gradle.properties have access to environment variables

Tags: java, gradle, environment-variables, build.gradle, gradle.properties

I looked around and could not find any way of accessing environment variables in my gradle.properties.

**What I can do:** In my build.gradle I can access environment variables like this `System.getenv("MY_VAR")`. I would like to do the same in my gradle.properties.

**Example of what I want to do:** In my gradle.properties replace `build.foo=bar` with `build.foo=System.getenv("BAR")`

So far all my attempts to access environment variables from gradle.properties have failed.

Any insight into the matter would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> could not find any way of accessing environment variables in my gradle.properties.

You can't. `gradle.properties` is not anything fancy, it is a [standard properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

You would need to post-process the properties somehow as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263944/2382650). Currently, Gradle does not offer any such functionality to "custom load" `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 16):

Not all environment variables are visible to gradle. If you can name them with the special prefix `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_` these will be available. You can read about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties)

`ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_foo` can be accessed as `foo` within gradle.

Comment: Your statement is true in that only the specially named env variables get autoloaded into gradle's internal properties. But you can explicitly use System.getEnv('ENV_VAR") to load any envrionment variable into gradle scripts.

Comment: This is true in Gradle v7.5.1 and likely some number of versions before that, but `latest` (i.e., `current` or 8.5) doesn't mention it.

The v7.5.1 doc. equivalent:

https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties

It's not clear to me whether this functionality is maintained in v8.0.0+

Answer (score 3):

According this [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:project_properties) documentation. Environment Variable that follows this name pattern "ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_foo=bar" will be added as a gradle property with the name "foo"

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
"... but if an option is configured in multiple locations, the first one wins:

system properties, e.g. when -Dgradle.user.home is set on the command line."

In Unix you could do like this: -Dgradle.user.home=$GRADLE_USER_HOME